# "Heap inspection" vulnerability

Tags: java

I need to pass a password to a call. If I do

```
byte[] dataSourcePasswdDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(dataSourcePasswdEncoded);
String dataSourcePasswd = new String(dataSourcePasswdDecoded);
hikariDataSource.setPassword(dataSourcePasswd);
```

When the code got scanned by Fortify, it was reported the code has an vulnerability of "Heap inspection" due to the assignment of password to a String.

Fortify does not complain the original code:

```
 hikariDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
```

even though env.getProperty() does return a String.

What Fortify recommend is:

```
private JPasswordField pf;
...
final char[] password = pf.getPassword();
// use the password
...
// erase when finished
Arrays.fill(password, ' ');
```

But how can you use char[] as password when the function expect a String?

Comment: I would pass a [`HikariConfig`](https://github.com/openbouquet/HikariCP/blob/master/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java) to `ds = new HikariDataSource( config );` and don't do this weird Base64 encoding of your password in the first place.

Comment: What is your scanner definition of this vulnerability?

Comment: the definition is: stores sensitive data in a String object, making it impossible to reliably purge the data from memory. since String objects are immutable, removing the value of a String from memory can only be done by the JVM garbage collector. The garbage collector is not required to run unless the JVM is low on memory, so there is no guarantee as to when garbage collection will take place. In the event of an application crash, a memory dump of the application might reveal sensitive data.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Base64 is not for encryption purpose. I can get rid of it. But still setPassword expect a String

Comment: @techie11 Base64 != [Encryption](http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-passwords.html). Base64 is barely obfuscation.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Base64 is NOT for encryption purpose. I can get rid of it. But still setPassword expect a String

Comment: @techie11 Fascinating. `public HikariConfig(Properties properties)` does **not** take a `String`. So you **could** construct a `HikariConfig` by passing in a `Properties`. And you could load the `Properties` without needing to call `setPassword` at all. Best of luck!

Comment: And ... you would still passing the password (in the `Properties` object) as a `String`.  Whether or not your checker notices it.   Frankly, what this checker is doing in this case is "performative security".

Comment: At that rate, don't even pass it to the _Arrays_ class, just manually replace each value.  All in all, it seems like a lost cause.  I would suggest using _[VisualVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualVM)_, to see the how effective it is.

Answer (score 4):

Yea ... base64 encoding a password is no protection at all.  Any hacker with half a brain knows how to recognize and decode base64.  So your "weird base64 stuff" is not helping.

But the flipside is that your vulnerability scanner is pointing out a problem that is relatively hard to exploit, AND is probably not going to be solvable anyway.

At some point in your application (its dependencies, or somewhere) the password is going to be converted into a Java `String` ... because some API requires a `String`.  At that point you have a "heap inspection" vulnerability whether or not the scanner tells you about it.  For instance, if the data source uses JDBC, that password needs to be passed as a parameter to a `DriverManager.connect` call.  There are 3 overloads for `connect` ... but they all entail passing the password as a clear-text string.  Fixing that is impractical.

<sup>(Clearly, the so-called fix suggested by Fortify is obviously not going to work.  And it fails to notice that your call to `setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"))` is just a "bad" as what you are currently doing.  This is "performative security" ...)</sup>

---

The most practical solution is to tell the scanner that this is a "false positive".  Then take steps to prevent hackers from being able to attach a debugger, inspect RAM, core dumps, swap disks, etc and trawl through the heap looking for String objects that might represent passwords.

---

There is also a "nasty" solution that entails **smashing** through type abstraction on the `String` object and overwriting its backing array.  But that approach is fragile.

- The representation of `String` has changed a number of times over the life of Java, and each change would potentially break your `String` overwriting code.
- In some circumstances the backing array of a `String` is shared with other `String` objects and smashing the backing array will damage those objects.
- There is the problem of finding all of the cases where the password `String` *might* have been copied or inserted into other `String` objects.

Unless you are dealing with *classified information*, this is (IMO) over the top.  And if you *are* dealing with classified information, secure your platform before you go to these lengths.  (And don't rely on dumb security scanner software to do your security audits!)

Answer (score 1):

Evidently you need to call an existing method that takes a String argument which is a password.

Therefore you must give it a String argument that is a password.

Whether or not you assign the String to an intermediate variable, it is still a String that is a password. There is no security difference between having a variable or not. There is one String either way.

Of course, if your scanner is too stupid to notice a String that is not assigned to a variable, maybe that will work.
'

```
hikariDataSource.setPassword(new String(dataSourcePasswdDecoded));
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I work around this?

Comment: Disable the stupid scanner that gets in the way of you doing your job.  Or, if there's some notation you can add to your code to say 'ignore this issue on this line', use that. You might try not using the word 'password' anywhere, but you're probably stuck with that call to 'setPassword' in someone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

inline it?

```
hikariDataSource.setPassword(new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dataSourcePasswdEncoded)));
```

Comment: thanks for you reponse, but doesn't jvm still store the password with hikari password holder variable pointing to it instead of his own dataSourcePassword?
will the outcome be the same or the hikari has it's own protection mechanism?

Comment: seems like hikari doesnt prevent heap inspection, to be honest I dont think you can prevent it anyways. at some point a string will reach the heap, you can prevent your static code analyzer from complaining though. btw [here is a nice article](https://westonal.medium.com/protecting-strings-in-jvm-memory-84c365f8f01c)

Comment: Thanks my friend, The only solution I could think of was extending the HikariConfig class and making the getPassword() method decrypt an encrypted password stored in heap with it's predefined key and return it every time it gets called.
Hope this helps to solve the problem.